# Optimizing Cypher Query for performance

Tags: neo4j

This is a follow up question to my previous question:[Correct way to create json from neo4j rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489549/correct-way-to-create-json-from-neo4j-rest-api#).

I was able to get the JSON exactly in the format I required with the help provided to me by @Michael Hunger. Following is the code:

```
    MATCH (mainCap:Capability{SectorID:"PNU"})  
    OPTIONAL MATCH  (mainCap)-[r1:CapabilityAdopts_Capability]->(adoptsCap1)    
    OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r2:KPI_Capability]->(capKPI)
    OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r4:Capability_Capability]->(cap1)         
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)<-[r5:Capability_Capability]-(isPart1)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)-[r6:KPI_Capability]->(KPI1)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)-[r7:Capability_Capability]->(cap2)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)<-[r8:Capability_Capability]-(isPart2)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)-[r9:KPI_Capability]->(KPI2)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)-[r10:Capability_Capability]->(cap3)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap3)<-[r11:Capability_Capability]-(isPart3)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap3)-[r12:KPI_Capability]->(KPI3)

    OPTIONAL MATCH (mainCap)<-[r3:Capability_Capability]-(isPart:Capability)                                                                                                        
    with
        mainCap as mainCap, 
        isPart as isPart,
        adoptsCap1 as adoptsCap1,
        cap1 as cap1,
        cap2 as cap2,
        cap3 as cap3,
        KPI2 as KPI2,
        isPart2 as isPart2,
        KPI1 as KPI1,
        isPart1 as isPart1,
        capKPI as capKPI,
        CASE WHEN KPI3 IS NOT NULL THEN
        COLLECT(DISTINCT
          {
            _id: KPI3.ExternalID,
            type: labels(KPI3)[0],
            name: KPI3.Name,
            description: KPI3.Description,
            sectorID: KPI3.SectorID,
            CCO: KPI3.CCO,
            CFO: KPI3.CFO,
            SVPHR: KPI3.SVPHR,
            area: KPI3.Area,
            CEO: KPI3.CEO,
            CIO: KPI3.CIO,
            COO: KPI3.COO       
          }
        )
      ELSE
        []
        END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn3,

        CASE WHEN isPart3 IS NOT NULL THEN
            COLLECT(DISTINCT
              {
              _id: isPart3.ExternalID,
                type: labels(isPart3)[0]                        
              }
            )
          ELSE
            []
            END as isPartOfCapability3      

                    with

                    mainCap as mainCap, 
                    isPart as isPart,
                    adoptsCap1 as adoptsCap1,
                    cap1 as cap1,
                    cap2 as cap2,                   
                    KPI1 as KPI1,
                    isPart1 as isPart1,
                    capKPI as capKPI,
                    CASE WHEN cap3 IS NOT NULL THEN
                    COLLECT(DISTINCT
                      {
                      _id: cap3.ExternalID,
                        type: labels(cap3)[0],
                        name: cap3.Name,
                        description: cap3.Overview,
                        sectorID: cap3.SectorID,
                        cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn3,
                        isPartOfCapability:isPartOfCapability3
                      }
                    )
                  ELSE
                    []
                    END as consistsOfCapability3,           


                    CASE WHEN KPI2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                    COLLECT(DISTINCT
                      {
                        _id: KPI2.ExternalID,
                        type: labels(KPI2)[0],
                        name: KPI2.Name,
                        description: KPI2.Description,
                        sectorID: KPI2.SectorID,
                        CCO: KPI2.CCO,
                        CFO: KPI2.CFO,
                        SVPHR: KPI2.SVPHR,
                        area: KPI2.Area,
                        CEO: KPI2.CEO,
                        CIO: KPI2.CIO,
                        COO: KPI2.COO       
                      }
                    )
                  ELSE
                    []
                    END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn2,

                    CASE WHEN isPart2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                        COLLECT(DISTINCT
                          {
                          _id: isPart2.ExternalID,
                            type: labels(isPart2)[0]                        
                          }
                        )
                      ELSE
                        []
                        END as isPartOfCapability2              

                            with mainCap as mainCap,
                                adoptsCap1 as adoptsCap1,
                                isPart as isPart,
                                cap1 as cap1,                               
                                capKPI as capKPI,
                            CASE WHEN cap2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                              {
                              _id: cap2.ExternalID,
                                type: labels(cap2)[0],
                                name: cap2.Name,
                                description: cap2.Overview,
                                sectorID: cap2.SectorID,
                                cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn2,
                                isPartOfCapability:isPartOfCapability2,
                                consistsOfCapability:consistsOfCapability3
                              }
                            )
                          ELSE
                            []
                            END as consistsOfCapability2,                   


                            CASE WHEN KPI1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                              {
                                _id: KPI1.ExternalID,
                                type: labels(KPI1)[0],
                                name: KPI1.Name,
                                description: KPI1.Description,
                                sectorID: KPI1.SectorID,
                                CCO: KPI1.CCO,
                                CFO: KPI1.CFO,
                                SVPHR: KPI1.SVPHR,
                                area: KPI1.Area,
                                CEO: KPI1.CEO,
                                CIO: KPI1.CIO,
                                COO: KPI1.COO           
                              }
                            )
                          ELSE
                            []
                            END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,

                            CASE WHEN isPart1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                  {
                                  _id: isPart1.ExternalID,
                                    type: labels(isPart1)[0]                        
                                  }
                                )
                              ELSE
                                []
                                END as isPartOfCapability1  

                                    with mainCap as mainCap,
                                    adoptsCap1 as adoptsCap1,
                                    isPart as isPart,
                                    CASE WHEN cap1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                    COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                      {
                                      _id: cap1.ExternalID,
                                        type: labels(cap1)[0],
                                        name: cap1.Name,
                                        description: cap1.Overview,
                                        sectorID: cap1.SectorID,
                                        cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,
                                        isPartOfCapability:isPartOfCapability1,
                                        consistsOfCapability:consistsOfCapability2
                                      }
                                    )
                                    ELSE
                                    []
                                    END as consistsOfCapability1,

                                    CASE WHEN capKPI IS NOT NULL THEN
                                        COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                          {
                                            _id: capKPI.ExternalID,
                                            type: labels(capKPI)[0],
                                            name: capKPI.Name,
                                            description: capKPI.Description,
                                            sectorID: capKPI.SectorID,
                                            CCO: capKPI.CCO,
                                            CFO: capKPI.CFO,
                                            SVPHR: capKPI.SVPHR,
                                            area: capKPI.Area,
                                            CEO: capKPI.CEO,
                                            CIO: capKPI.CIO,
                                            COO: capKPI.COO 
                                          }
                                        )
                                      ELSE
                                        []
                                        END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn

        return {
                        _id:mainCap.ExternalID, 
                        type:labels(mainCap)[0],
                        name:mainCap.Name,
                        adoptsCapability: 

                                CASE WHEN adoptsCap1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                                COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                                  {
                                                    _id: adoptsCap1.ExternalID,
                                                    type: labels(adoptsCap1)[0],
                                                    name: adoptsCap1.Name,
                                                    description: adoptsCap1.Overview,
                                                    sectorID: adoptsCap1.SectorID,
                                                    cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,
                                                    consistsOfCapability:consistsOfCapability1                                                  
                                                  }
                                                )
                                                ELSE
                                                []
                                                END,
                        isPartOfCapability:             
                                CASE WHEN isPart IS NOT NULL THEN
                                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                              {
                                              _id: isPart.ExternalID,
                                                type: labels(isPart)[0]                     
                                              }
                                            )
                                          ELSE
                                            []
                                            END 



        }as `col2`
```

The above query take **4149 ms** to give results. I tried to optimize using distinct. Went through: 
http://thought-bytes.blogspot.com/2013/01/optimizing-neo4j-cypher-queries.html.
[Optimize Neo4j Cypher query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146883/optimize-neo4j-cypher-query)
More relevant: [Optimizing Cypher queries with lots of optional relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721048/optimizing-cypher-queries-with-lots-of-optional-relationships)

**Question: Is it possible to optimize and reduce the time to around ~2 seconds further? I have an angularjs UI which has a menu in bound to data coming from neo. its is currently taking 4.4 seconds to get data from neo**  Or is this maximum performance I can get out of this query?

Following is my execution plan:
[image]

Help appreciated. Thanks

**Following is the Solution:**

The performance improved drastically after reformatting the query. The cardinalities were causing performance lag. **From 4149ms it came down to 400ms**:

```
    match (mainCap:Capability{SectorID:"PNU"}) 
                OPTIONAL MATCH  (mainCap:Capability)-[r1:CapabilityAdopts_Capability]->(adoptsCap1) 
                                            OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r2:KPI_Capability]->(capKPI)
                                            OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r4:Capability_Capability]->(cap1) 

                                            with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cap1,
                                            CASE WHEN capKPI IS NOT NULL THEN
                                        COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                          {
                                            _id: capKPI.ExternalID,
                                            type: labels(capKPI)[0],
                                            name: capKPI.Name,
                                            description: capKPI.Description,
                                            sectorID: capKPI.SectorID,
                                            CCO: capKPI.CCO,
                                            CFO: capKPI.CFO,
                                            SVPHR: capKPI.SVPHR,
                                            area: capKPI.Area,
                                            CEO: capKPI.CEO,
                                            CIO: capKPI.CIO,
                                            COO: capKPI.COO 
                                          }
                                        )
                                      ELSE
                                        []
                                        END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn


                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)<-[r5:Capability_Capability]-(isPart1)
                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)-[r6:KPI_Capability]->(KPI1)
                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)-[r7:Capability_Capability]->(cap2)

                                        with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cap1,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,cap2,
                                            CASE WHEN KPI1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                              {
                                                _id: KPI1.ExternalID,
                                                type: labels(KPI1)[0],
                                                name: KPI1.Name,
                                                description: KPI1.Description,
                                                sectorID: KPI1.SectorID,
                                                CCO: KPI1.CCO,
                                                CFO: KPI1.CFO,
                                                SVPHR: KPI1.SVPHR,
                                                area: KPI1.Area,
                                                CEO: KPI1.CEO,
                                                CIO: KPI1.CIO,
                                                COO: KPI1.COO           
                                              }
                                            )
                                          ELSE
                                            []
                                            END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,

                                            CASE WHEN isPart1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                                COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                                  {
                                                  _id: isPart1.ExternalID,
                                                    type: labels(isPart1)[0]                        
                                                  }
                                                )
                                              ELSE
                                                []
                                                END as isPartOfCapability1  


                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)<-[r8:Capability_Capability]-(isPart2)
                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)-[r9:KPI_Capability]->(KPI2)
                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)-[r10:Capability_Capability]->(cap3)

                                        with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cap1,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,cap2,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,isPartOfCapability1,cap3,

                                        CASE WHEN KPI2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                        COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                          {
                                            _id: KPI2.ExternalID,
                                            type: labels(KPI2)[0],
                                            name: KPI2.Name,
                                            description: KPI2.Description,
                                            sectorID: KPI2.SectorID,
                                            CCO: KPI2.CCO,
                                            CFO: KPI2.CFO,
                                            SVPHR: KPI2.SVPHR,
                                            area: KPI2.Area,
                                            CEO: KPI2.CEO,
                                            CIO: KPI2.CIO,
                                            COO: KPI2.COO       
                                          }
                                        )
                                      ELSE
                                        []
                                        END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn2,

                                        CASE WHEN isPart2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                              {
                                              _id: isPart2.ExternalID,
                                                type: labels(isPart2)[0]                        
                                              }
                                            )
                                          ELSE
                                            []
                                            END as isPartOfCapability2

                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap3)<-[r11:Capability_Capability]-(isPart3)                                                                                                                                    
                                        OPTIONAL MATCH (cap3)-[r12:KPI_Capability]->(KPI3)

                                        with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cap1,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,cap2,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,isPartOfCapability1,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn2,isPartOfCapability2,cap3,

                                        CASE WHEN KPI3 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                        COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                          {
                                            _id: KPI3.ExternalID,
                                            type: labels(KPI3)[0],
                                            name: KPI3.Name,
                                            description: KPI3.Description,
                                            sectorID: KPI3.SectorID,
                                            CCO: KPI3.CCO,
                                            CFO: KPI3.CFO,
                                            SVPHR: KPI3.SVPHR,
                                            area: KPI3.Area,
                                            CEO: KPI3.CEO,
                                            CIO: KPI3.CIO,
                                            COO: KPI3.COO       
                                          }
                                        )
                                      ELSE
                                        []
                                        END as cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn3,

                                        CASE WHEN isPart3 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                              {
                                              _id: isPart3.ExternalID,
                                                type: labels(isPart3)[0]                        
                                              }
                                            )
                                          ELSE
                                            []
                                            END as isPartOfCapability3  



                                        with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cap1,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,cap2,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,isPartOfCapability1,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn2,isPartOfCapability2,

                                        CASE WHEN cap3 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                        COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                          {
                                          _id: cap3.ExternalID,
                                            type: labels(cap3)[0],
                                            name: cap3.Name,
                                            description: cap3.Overview,
                                            sectorID: cap3.SectorID,
                                            cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn3,
                                            isPartOfCapability:isPartOfCapability3
                                          }
                                        )
                                      ELSE
                                        []
                                        END as consistsOfCapability3


                                    with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cap1,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,isPartOfCapability1,

                                    CASE WHEN cap2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                    COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                      {
                                      _id: cap2.ExternalID,
                                        type: labels(cap2)[0],
                                        name: cap2.Name,
                                        description: cap2.Overview,
                                        sectorID: cap2.SectorID,
                                        cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn2,
                                        isPartOfCapability:isPartOfCapability2,
                                        consistsOfCapability:consistsOfCapability3
                                      }
                                    )
                                  ELSE
                                    []
                                    END as consistsOfCapability2

                                    with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,

                                    CASE WHEN cap1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                                    COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                      {
                                      _id: cap1.ExternalID,
                                        type: labels(cap1)[0],
                                        name: cap1.Name,
                                        description: cap1.Overview,
                                        sectorID: cap1.SectorID,
                                        cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn1,
                                        isPartOfCapability:isPartOfCapability1,
                                        consistsOfCapability:consistsOfCapability2
                                      }
                                    )
                                    ELSE
                                    []
                                    END as consistsOfCapability1


OPTIONAL MATCH (mainCap)<-[r3:Capability_Capability]-(isPart:Capability)

return {
model:{ 

    _id:mainCap.ExternalID, 
    type:labels(mainCap)[0],
    name:mainCap.Name,

    adoptsCapability: 

            CASE WHEN adoptsCap1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                              {
                                _id: adoptsCap1.ExternalID,
                                type: labels(adoptsCap1)[0],
                                name: adoptsCap1.Name,
                                description: adoptsCap1.Overview,
                                sectorID: adoptsCap1.SectorID,
                                cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn:cpbltyIsMsrdByKpiPttrn,
                                consistsOfCapability:consistsOfCapability1

                              }
                            )
                            ELSE
                            []
                            END,

                            isPartOfCapability:             
                                CASE WHEN isPart IS NOT NULL THEN
                                            COLLECT(DISTINCT
                                              {
                                              _id: isPart.ExternalID,
                                                type: labels(isPart)[0]                     
                                              }
                                            )
                                          ELSE
                                            []
                                            END 




    }

}
```

Comment: Protip: You don't need to use `mainCap as mainCap` in your `WITH`.  If the alias variable is the same as the variable in the query you can just say `WITH mainCap, isPart, adoptsCap1, etc...`

Comment: Another thing that I noticed is that you're copying all of the properties for the `KPI3` variable in order to return the first label.  If you query the transactions endpoints you can pass "REST" for the "resultDataContents " to get labels.  If you can get that with your library depends on your library.  See: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-execute-statements-in-an-open-transaction-in-rest-format-for-the-return

Comment: Update to 2.2.5 from 2.2.0

Comment: Can you by chance share your database or an example database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add an constraint or index

for your start-node:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (mainCap:Capability) assert mainCap.SectorID IS UNIQUE;
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Capability(SectorID);
```

#### Reduce Cardinalities

The biggest point is to get your in-between cardinalities down.

Otherwise each row that a previous statement produces is repeatedly matched, no matter if it was a duplicate row or not.

```
MATCH (mainCap:Capability{SectorID:"PNU"})  
    OPTIONAL MATCH  (mainCap)-[r1:CapabilityAdopts_Capability]->(adoptsCap1)-[r2:KPI_Capability]->(capKPI),
    OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r4:Capability_Capability]->(cap1)         
// reduce cardinality
with mainCap, adoptsCap1, cap1, collect(distinct capKPI) as _capKPI
    OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)<-[r5:Capability_Capability]-(isPart1)
with mainCap,  adoptsCap1, cap1, _capKPI, collect(isPart1) as _isPart1
...
```

PS You don't need aliases if the name is not changing like here `mainCap as mainCap,`

And try to work your way from the top, profiling as you go.

Comment: The performance improved drastically after reformatting the query. The cardinalities were causing performance lag. From 4149ms it came down to 400ms. Thanks again.I posted the solution above. Db hits are in 100s not in 1000s

Answer (score 0):

Really quick suggestion to try, depending on the version of Neo4j you're using (before or after 2.2.0):

Try combining all of your `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses like this:

```
MATCH (mainCap:Capability{SectorID:"PNU"})  
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (mainCap)-[r1:CapabilityAdopts_Capability]->(adoptsCap1),
  (adoptsCap1)-[r2:KPI_Capability]->(capKPI),
  (adoptsCap1)-[r4:Capability_Capability]->(cap1),
  (cap1)<-[r5:Capability_Capability]-(isPart1),
  (cap1)-[r6:KPI_Capability]->(KPI1),
  (cap1)-[r7:Capability_Capability]->(cap2),
  (cap2)<-[r8:Capability_Capability]-(isPart2),
  (cap2)-[r9:KPI_Capability]->(KPI2),
  (cap2)-[r10:Capability_Capability]->(cap3),
  (cap3)<-[r11:Capability_Capability]-(isPart3),
  (cap3)-[r12:KPI_Capability]->(KPI3),

  (mainCap)<-[r3:Capability_Capability]-(isPart:Capability)
```

Instead of this:

```
MATCH (mainCap:Capability{SectorID:"PNU"})  
OPTIONAL MATCH  (mainCap)-[r1:CapabilityAdopts_Capability]->(adoptsCap1)    
OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r2:KPI_Capability]->(capKPI)
OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r4:Capability_Capability]->(cap1)         
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)<-[r5:Capability_Capability]-(isPart1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)-[r6:KPI_Capability]->(KPI1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap1)-[r7:Capability_Capability]->(cap2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)<-[r8:Capability_Capability]-(isPart2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)-[r9:KPI_Capability]->(KPI2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap2)-[r10:Capability_Capability]->(cap3)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap3)<-[r11:Capability_Capability]-(isPart3)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cap3)-[r12:KPI_Capability]->(KPI3)

OPTIONAL MATCH (mainCap)<-[r3:Capability_Capability]-(isPart:Capability)
```

**EDIT:**

I didn't read the query very closely because I was about to hop onto a call, but you could also combine them like this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH  (mainCap)-[r1:CapabilityAdopts_Capability]->(adoptsCap1)-[r2:KPI_Capability]->(capKPI)
```

Neo4j is smart enough to process it fine either way, so it's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Are you missing a statement in your suggestion?..Try combining all of your OPTIONAL MATCH clauses like this:....??  I am using 2.2.0

Comment: I combined your first two `OPTIONAL MATCH` statements into one `OPTIONAL MATCH` statement using comma syntax.  I've edited to make it clearer

Comment: i cannot combine them as 
 OPTIONAL MATCH  (mainCap)-[r1:CapabilityAdopts_Capability]-      >   (adoptsCap1)-[r2:KPI_Capability]->(capKPI)
 
because there there are nodes which are related to main and adoptsCap1 but not to capKPI. I need those nodes as well.

Comment: You should still be able to combine all of the clauses together and it should work.  I was being lazy, but I'll update my question with what I mean

Comment: Regardless I should say that the profile output seems to be indicating that the variables hanging off the ends of your `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses (like `cap1`, `cap2`, 'isPart2', 'KPI2', etc...) are matching on the entire database each time.  If any of those could be non-optional matches that would help.  Otherwise you could use labels to narrow things down, if that's applicable.

Comment: removing optional match and replacing with comman delayed execution by 800ms there by taking total time to 5100ms. Putting back optional match. Now trying to see if I can make end variables non optional. Can you please clarify what you mean by "use labels to narrow things down".

Comment: Like this like for example: `OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r4:Capability_Capability]->(cap1)` if the `cap1` always refers to a Capability you could do `OPTIONAL MATCH  (adoptsCap1)-[r4:Capability_Capability]->(cap1:Capability)`.  That will narrow down the list (unless the entire database is `Capability` nodes...)